# add RelativeLayout to Canvas

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-relativelayout, android-canvas

I have created a custom view by extending View

```
class CustomView extends View{
 ...
 @Override
 public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){}
 ...
```

}

I want to draw a RelativeLayout inside my custom view. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is that instead of extending `View`, extend a class from `ViewGroup`, such as a `RelativeLayout`.

Remember this `ViewGroup` will still be a `View`, it will just come with a few more methods that simplify adding other views.

Comment: When I do that everything I draw by overriding `onDraw` disappear. That may have to do with `onLayout`. How do I implement that method?

Comment: Make sure you call `super.onDraw(canvas)` before drawing and that you call `setWillNotDraw(false)` in the constructor.